# Invalid service name [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=name] in gcp connect twilio messaging with dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created one agent in Dialogflow and then connect it with GCP Function with Webhook. And now I want to integrate it with Twilio text messaging so that I follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio#readme tutorial but when I put the command:

```
"gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/test1/dialogflow-twilio--update-env-vars GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=test1.json --memory 1Gi"
```

it gives me error that

```
(gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Invalid service name [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=name]. 
Service name must use only lowercase alphanumeric characters 
and dashes. Cannot begin or end with a dash, and cannot be longer than 63 characters...
```

My gcloud sdk version is 290.0.1. I have created a service account in which have given access to dialogflow-client and use that account json file. Help me what I am missing in this please.

Comment: What's your `gcloud version` command line result?

Comment: it is Google Cloud SDK 290.0.1
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.56
core 2020.04.24
gsutil 4.49

Answer (score 0):

You must be entering `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=name` whenever the command prompts you to enter a service name. In this case you can simply hit enter and it will create a default service name for you.

From [README.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio#deploying-the-integration-using-cloud-run):

> When prompted for a service name hit enter to accept the default.

Edit:

Run your command like this (add a space between `dialogflow-twilio` and `--update env-vars`):

```
gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/test1/dialogflow-twilio --update-env-vars GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=test1.json --memory 1Gi
```

Comment: It is not prompting me for service_name. It directly gives error.

Comment: Based on your sample command it should prompt you an option to create a service name after choosing a target platform. Could you edit your post and enter the specific command that you're running?

Comment: please update your post with the error log, and also include your gcloud version

Answer (score 0):

The current Google Cloud SDK version is 316. There is 1 release per week. If yours is 290, that means you are 26 weeks behind, roughly 6 month.

Update your gcloud SDK, it should fix your issue (the error message simply don't know the param that you use! And take the param value as the name of the Cloud Run service)

Try a `gcloud components update`